# regex not detecting space in username textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a asp:textbox taking a Username that is part of a Signup form for a new user account.

Obviously I don't want the user to sign up using a space as a name so I have this regular expression which should keep the valid entry to ASCII characters between 3 and 16 in length with NO SPACES.

but the no spaces doesn't work in practice. it works in Regex editors and checkers but not my aspx page.

Any suggestions?

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()-_=+;:'"|~`<>?/{}]{3,16})$|\s
```

many thanks

Comment: That's the expression, where's the code? If the expression is correct, then it follows that the code must be wrong. Or maybe the compiler, but don't count on it.

Comment: Its just an <asp:RegularExpressionValidator> bound to a textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your having trouble understanding what dtb is trying to say.  Let me break-down the regex for you and you will see what he is saying:

```
^ - matches the beginning of the input string
( - begins a capture group, in your case useless and can be removed along with the closing ) just before the $
[ - begins a group of characters
a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()-_=+;:'"|~`?/{} - defines all the characters allowed, NOTICE there is no space character so spaces will not count
] - ends the group of characters
{3,16} - says that the preceding character(or group of characters in this case) must occur between 3 and 16 times
) - closes the capture group, again can be removed with the open (
$ - matches the end of the input string
```

This is where your expression goes awry...

```
| - says that the preceeding match expression (this is the $ which is the end of input) OR the following must be true, but not necessarily both
\s - matches a space or tab anywhere in the input string
```

So (if I'm reading this correctly) your regex states:

"I match a string if the string starts with ascii characters and is 3 to 16 characters in length before it finds either the end of the string or some whitespace (tab or space)."

To fix it, remove the '|\s' from the end of your expression and just use the following:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()-_=+;:'"|~`<>?/{}]{3,16})$
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't going mad, it appears there is some problem with the way the expression is used. My page still allows me to enter spaces undetected. the string is fine though. I've picked the spaces out with an if statement now to save time. Thanks though!

Answer (score 5):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()-_=+;:'"|~`?/{}]{3,16})$|\s
                                               ↑
```

Your current regex says: *"I match a string if the string is made of these characters and is 3 to 16 characters in length **OR** if it contains a whitespace character."*

So, if you don't want it to match spaces, remove **`|\s`** (i.e. the 'or' operator and the whitespace pattern) from the regex.

Comment: i need it to detect spaces though

Comment: Your current regex says: "I match if the string is made of these characters and 3 to 16 characters in length OR if it contains a space"

Comment: Ok i'm a novice sorry. any advice on how to modify it so it matches the characters and is 3-16 in length and contains no spaces?

Comment: Just remove `|\s` from the end of the regex.

Comment: ok. here so we have
^([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()-_=+;:'"|~`?/{}]{3,16})$

That matches anything that is NOT a string of ASCII between 3-16 in length. So now I want it to stop when it detects a space. what shall i add?

Comment: @David: No, that matches anything that **is** such a string - the leading `^` means "the start of the string", not **NOT**.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, replace the `$` at the end with `($|\s)` But to be sure you should add some examples of valid and invalid input to your question. Note the parentheses around `($|\s)`

Answer (score 0):

A simpler answer would be:

```
^([^\s]{3,16})$
```

which means "the whole string must consist of three to sixteen repeats of anything other than whitespace."

That will allow accented characters as well, but that's probably something you'll need to accept anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler still is

```
^\S{3,16}$
```